# Declaring an array with a hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, arrays, hex

What is the benefit in declaring an array with a size in hexadecimal format?
Does the compiler convert the hexadecimal to binary quicker than it would decimal numbers?

For example:

```
int array [0x1480];  
int array0[5248];
sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array) == sizeof(array0)/sizeof(*array0) //simply a true statement
```

Comment: Not at all. This is purely a programer believing that the hex notation improved readability in some way.

Comment: @aruisdante Post the same as answer!

Comment: Since the compiler has to process 6 characters for the hex constant but just 4 characters for the decimal constant, processing the hex will be marginally (but immeasurably) slower than processing the decimal.  However, neither notation has a 'real' performance benefit; it is a question of notational convenience to the programmer.  Presumably, there is a reason why the hex constant is a better choice than the decimal (though it is not obvious why that value was chosen, whether in hex or decimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all. This is purely a programer believing that the hex notation improved readability in some way.

Answer (score -1):

A const in C++ can be presented as decimal, octal and hex literals.
See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/ for details.

So below numbers are identical:

```
5248    // decimal
0x1480  // hex
012200  // octal
```

Comment: That doesn't really address the OP's question, which is if using a hex literal actually *maters* in some context.

Comment: It states that they are *identical*, why do you think it's not an answer?